# type-declaration file for non-module in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, type-declaration

I'm building a website for [Beaker Browser](https://beakerbrowser.com/) using [Angular6](https://angular.io/).

Beaker Browser has a built-in class called `DatArchive`. I want to create a type-declaration file for it.

When this class was used in only one file, I simply wrote

```
declare class DatArchive {
  static selectArchive(opts: any): Promise<DatArchive>;
  static create(opts: any): Promise<DatArchive>;
  constructor(datUrl: String);
  url: string;
}
```

in the file and everything worked like a charm. However, when I wanted to extract it into its own file, I tried:

```
export declare class DatArchive {
  static selectArchive(opts: any): Promise<DatArchive>;
  static create(opts: any): Promise<DatArchive>;
  constructor(datUrl: String);
  url: string;
}
...
// in other files
import { DatArchive } from 'dat-archive';
```

And although it passed compilation, in runtime, seemingly, it was looking for a `DatArchive` inside a module, but a `DatArchive` is a top-level (on `window` object) class.

So, the question:

**In Angular/Typescript, how to write a type-declaration file for a class that is NOT part of a module?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write this in a declaration file (call it `beaker-browser.d.ts`):

```
declare class DatArchive {
  static selectArchive(opts: any): Promise<DatArchive>;
  static create(opts: any): Promise<DatArchive>;
  constructor(datUrl: String);
  url: string;
}
```

Putting this into a declaration file makes it a global declaration, so just can you just use `let dataArchive = new DataArchive(url);` without importing anything.

This is because you don't need to import anything, as the code itself is already in the environment. Creating a declaration file you just tell the compiler that such a class exists, without providing a definition (similar to what you were doing initially, but available to the whole project).